# An unfair coin with different face value problem

Tags: probability, density-function

Could any one give me some hints for the following problem:
A coin has two face: 1 and -1/2,  and the probability for 1 is $P(x=1)=1/3$ and for $-1/2$ is $P(x=-1/2)=2/3$. The expected value is therefore $E(x)=1\cdot(1/3)+(-1/2)\cdot(2/3) = 0$.
Supposing for an infinite tossing, what's the chance that the average value would be bigger than $k$? (supposing the sample number is sufficiently large)

Since if the face value are 1 and 0, it is simply a binomial distribution and can be approximate by normal distribution, so I also want to know if this problem can be transformed into binomial distribution $P(x>k)$ ?

This is not any homework problem, but a problem I just think of and try to solve.

Comment: Actually, E(x) = 1*(1/3)+(-1/3)*2/3 = +1/9.

Comment: You can do two things. The law of big numbers tells you that the average will tend toward the expected value. Then the central limit theorem tells you that this average will follow a normal distribution, from which you can calculate the probability.

Comment: @user31264: sorry.  it should be -1/2 for the negative face value. I changed that.

Comment: @Drew75: but it is not binomial distribution, how can I get the standard deviation for the asymptotic normal distribution ?

Comment: It's a scaled/shifted binomial.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the central limit theorem, for large number of tosses $n$, the total value is distributed normally as $N(0, \sigma)$, where $\sigma^2 = n \left( {1\over 3} 1^2 + {2 \over 3} (1/2)^2 \right) = {n \over 2}$.

Comment: Could you add a few words about *why* this is true and perhaps what $n$ must be to be considered "large"?

Comment: The question is obviously theoretical, and the author writes "Supposing for an infinite tossing", so the question what $n$ must be considered large have no sense.  As to why - because of the central limit theorem.